# Conditional Formatting in VBA based on A Different Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro as a part of a larger project. The last bit is to apply conditional formatting to a cell in column V if the conditions are met in column W.

I get

> Runtime Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument error.

```vb
Sub ComConFormGreen()
'
' ComConForGreen Macro
'

'
    Columns("W:W").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""Each"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16752384
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13561798
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Columns("V:V").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""$W1=""Each"""""
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16752384
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13561798
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

The problem appears to be in the following line:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:="=""$W1=""Each"""""
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but what happens if you run the code with the wrong sheet accidently selected?  [how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional rule looks for the value in **xlCellValue**, but you are trying to resolve a formula, so you should use **xlExpression** instead.

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$W1=""Each"""
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!

Comment: @Icoeph, check the answer if it was helpful!